# MySql Custom Sequence

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to make a custom sequence in MySql to track records in a table.

So I have a table called `FOOD_ITEM` that tracks the nutrition data of foods. Each `FOOD_ITEM` record has columns `ID` (auto incremented primary key), `EMAIL` (for who created it), `NAME`, `SERVING_AMOUNT`, `SERVING_SIZE`, and then the nutrition data like `CALORIES` and `PROTEIN`.

I have a unique key set like this:

```
ALTER TABLE FOOD_ITEM
ADD CONSTRAINT FOOD_ITEM_UK_EMAIL_NAME_SERVING
UNIQUE (EMAIL, NAME, SERVING_AMOUNT, SERVING_SIZE);
```

So a user cannot have the same uniquely named food with the same serving size and amount. For instance, they cannot have two of a Banana with a serving size and amount as 1 ounce. It would have to be a Banana with 1 ounce, 2 ounces, etc...

I am trying to create a sequence that makes a unique ID (lets call it `SERVING_ID`) whenever a new serving size and/or amount is added for a food.

So the user with email user@user.com and food Banana will have Banana 1 ounce, Banana 2 ounces, Banana 5 grams, etc. with `SERVING_ID`'s 1, 2, 3, etc. respectively.

Then another user, iamauser@iamauser.com, can have Banana 1 ounce, Banana 2 ounces, etc. with `SERVING_ID`'s 1, 2, etc. also. So for every `EMAIL` and `NAME` when a new record with a new `SERVING_SIZE` and/or `SERVING_AMOUNT` is added then the sequence increments by 1.

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: For a unique record for each row, use `auto_increment` when you define the column.

Comment: @GordonLinoff It's not for each row, and my ID column already does that which I mentioned above. This is unique for only a new serving size or amount for a given food from a given user. I think I'm going to just handle it in code on the server.